# Limit at infinity $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right) = $

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right) = $

I have Tried like this way:: Let $x = k\rightarrow \infty$. Then Limit Convert into $\lim_{x\rightarrow k}(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)$

Now When $x = k\rightarrow \infty$. Then $x=\lfloor x \rfloor $.

So $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right) = 0$

But Answer given is Limit does not exists.

Comment: For what $N$ is it the case that $x > N$ implies the expression is $0$? How about $N = 1000$? No, that can't work, because if $x = 1000.5 > 1000$, then the expression is $0.5 \neq 0$...

Comment: sawtooth wave !!!.

Comment: Benjamin Dickman ,Felix Marin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit does not exist. Note that $x\mapsto x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ traces out all numbers in $[0,1)$ indefinitely many times as $x\to+\infty$ (to convince yourself, you may want to draw a graph; it's gonna be a sequence of segments pointing to the northeast). That is, there is not a particular number to which this function gets ever closer as $x$ tends to infinity (which, intuitively, is the very essence of the definition of convergence).

In your example, what you really show is that $$\lim_{\substack{x\to+\infty\\\text{$x$ is an integer}}}\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)=0.$$ This is elusive, because you have chosen only a *particular* sequence of $x$'s (namely, the sequence of integers) and shown that the associated sequence of function values converges to zero. However, by the definition of convergence, you ought to show this result for *all* sequences of $x$'s tending to infinity. But then again, you can't show this, because convergence does not occur.

Comment: Thanks triple_sec.................

Comment: @juantheron My pleasure!